# Differences between IE and FF when using jquery and textarea

Tags: jquery, apache, textarea, oracle-apex

This seems to be a simple issue, but so far I've been thwarted at almost every turn.

I am dynamically building a user interface using jquery and json using a list of ids that are returned from multiple selections.  Part of that interface includes a user justification which is dynamically created as such:

```
$('<textarea>').attr({
'rows': '5', 
'cols': '50', 
'name': appId,  
'id': 'AppJust' + appId}).appendTo('#contentColumn>#AppPanel' + appId);
```

Further on in the process I have the following code:

```
var userJustification = $('textarea[name=' + appId + ']').val() ;
```

In FF if I alert `userJustification` I get the text that was typed into the textarea.

In IE if I alert `userJustification` I get `undefined`.

I've also tried `var userJustification = $('textarea[name=' + appId + ']').attr('value') ;`
with the exact same results.

If I completely change:

```
var userJustification = $('textarea[name=' + appId + ']').val() ;
```

to:

```
var userJustification = $('textarea#AppJust' + appId).val() ;
```

It works...

My question is:

Why does the name approach work in FF and not IE?

**EDIT**

Using the information Scott posted, I was intrigued and I tinkered with the code a little bit.

```
var userJustification = $('textarea[name=' + appId + ']').val() ;
```

But it still does not work in my environment (IE7)... I'm not sure why or how because for all intents and purposes that should work properly.  Scott's fiddle proves this.

So for no good reason (by accident actually) made a tiny alteration to the code:

```
var userJustification = $('textarea[name = ' + appId + ']').val() ;
```

(notice the space before and after the '=' inside the selector)

And it works...  At first I thought it had something to do with appId being an integer... but even in fiddle if I change "One" to 25... it still works properly.

I verified in FF to see how it was being rendered.. and here is an example of how the text area looks when it is is created... nothing out of the ordinary:

```
<textarea id="AppJust40" rows="5" cols="50" name="40"></textarea>
```

Could it have something to do with the way the page itself is being rendered?  Its an Apex application on an Apache server????

Comment: Works for me in IE7 and IE8, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/Cmmmb/)

Comment: I have no idea... it made me throw my hands up in the air.

Comment: Yea, Patrick, that is very odd. What if you did `$('textarea[name="' + appId + '"]').val();`?  Does that work in IE7 for you?

Comment: Good suggestion... if i use $('textarea[name="' + appId + '"]').val(); then yes it does work in that format... I'm almost thinking that when the oracle apex server renders the page via apache it does something odd with the name which IE (as usual) doesn't understand so it doesn't work while FF being more flexible can figgure out what you intend.

Comment: What I'll have to do is use IE developer tools and see what it is doing... unfortunately I do not have access to the tools at this machine... it'll have to wait until later.

Comment: Its like IE thinks> number + string = cannot compute... while FF thinks > number + string... hmm they must intend the number to BE a string so ill concatenate... thats the only thing that I can come up with that may possibly cause the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our conversation in your comments, adding quotes around the attribute value solves the issue in IE7 for you:

```
$('textarea[name="' + appId + '"]').val();
```

Even though the ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/Cmmmb/)*** I first put in your comments works in both IE7 and IE8 without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's very odd, the only thing I can think is that IE doesn't support attribute selectors (CSS, [name=]). However this shouldn't matter as JQuery uses it's own engine to 'find' elements within the DOM.

I would recommend logging this as a bug on JQuery.

Comment: there are other areas in the application that I am using the name attribute selector and it works fine... i'm pulling the value of a group of radio buttons back via name on the exact same page and that hasn't given me any grief yet.